# How does Spell Sniper affect spells that allow ranged spell attacks on subsequent rounds?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats

The spells [Crown of Stars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/crown-of-stars), [Storm Sphere](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/storm-sphere), and [Wall of Light](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-light) all allow you to make ranged attacks on subsequent rounds.

> #### Wall of Light
>
> Until the spell ends, you can use an action to launch a beam of radiance from the wall at one creature you can see within 60 feet of it. Make a ranged spell attack. On a hit, the target takes 4d8 radiant damage.

> #### Storm Sphere
>
> Until the spell ends, you can use a bonus action on each of your turns to cause a bolt of lightning to leap from the center of the sphere toward one creature you choose within 60 feet of the center. Make a ranged spell attack. You have advantage on the attack roll if the target is in the sphere. On a hit, the target takes 4d6 lightning damage.

> #### Crown of Stars
>
> You can use a bonus action to send one of the motes streaking toward one creature or object within 120 feet of you. When you do so, make a ranged spell attack. On a hit, the target takes 4d12 radiant damage.

The spell sniper feat says:

> When you cast a spell that *requires* you to make an attack roll, the spell’s range is doubled.

To use all of the spells effects, you are required to make an attack roll. That is, they have functions that don't work without a attack roll.

Is that reading correct, and if so which of the ranges in each spell are effected?

Comment: Related: [Double Range for Storm Sphere with Spell Sniper](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119897), and of sorts [Which spells benefit from the Spell Sniper feat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/139154)